# Safari can't open the page “localhost:8080/console”. The error is: “Cancelled load from 'localhost:8080/console' because it is using HTTP/0.9.” (:0)

Tags: ios, mysql, safari, localhost

I am using a MacBook and I was trying to open http://localhost:8080/console in safari.
But every time there is the problem:

Cancelled load from 'http://localhost:8080/console' because it is using HTTP/0.9.” (:0)

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Safari is not the best browser for development, you can install Google Chrome or some other free browser

Comment: I also tried it on Google Chrome. There I got:
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE